# Constructing an explicit tower with quadratic extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am so confused as to where to even start with this problem:

a, b, c, and d are real numbers.
Let α = a + bi, β = c + di, such that α = β<sup>2</sup>.

Let Q be the set of rational numbers.  Let K be a field, such that Q ⊆ K and a, b ∈ K:

K<sub>0</sub> ⊂ K<sub>1</sub> ⊂ K<sub>2</sub> ⊂ ... ⊂ K<sub>r</sub> 
K = K<sub>0</sub> 
My job is to find r and construct an explicit tower while considering the following:

All [K<sub>j+1</sub> : K<sub>j</sub> ] = 2 
c, d ∈ K<sub>r</sub>  
All K<sub>i</sub> contain real elements (thus, we can't extend by i).

I've been trying to work with norms, but I just don't see it right now.  I'm hoping to implement the following theorem: 
If F and K are both fields, with [F:K] = 2, and characteristic of K not equal to 2, then ∃α ∈ F such that F = K(α) and α<sup>2</sup> = β ∈ K

A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence of primes $(p_n)_{n \geq 1}$. Then the following is what you want,

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},...) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},...,\sqrt{p_n})$$

Comment: I am extending by a finite number of elements.